# Use numpy argmax to find the first occurrence of value greater than 5 in the following array: arr = range(2, 20)

Tags: python, argmax

Use numpy argmax to find the first occurrence of value greater than 5 in the following array:

```
arr = range(2, 20)
```

Comment: That's not even an array

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(range(2, 20))
idx = np.argmax(np.concatenate((arr[arr <= 5], [arr[arr > 5][0]])))
```

or

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(range(2, 20))
idx = np.argmax(arr[arr <= 5]) + 1
```